# Play .mp4 using python and check if/while it is still playing

Tags: python, windows, audio

I'm using Windows 64 bit. I have tried several libraries. Couldnt' get pygame to work, couldnt' get pymedia to install on python 2.7.

Eventually got mplayer for python.

Installed it https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mplayer.py/

and I can get a sound file to play

```
import mplayer 
p = = mplayer.Player(args=(), stdout=mplayer.PIPE, stderr=None, autospawn=True)
p.loadfile('C:\mymusic.mp4') 
p.pause()
```

For some reason you have to call the pause command to get the audio to play.

The major problem arises when I want to start another sound playing. If I just call loadfile on another file it will already be playing so calling the the pause method will pause it rather than play it. If the first file has finished playing, the pause has to be called to play it.

Additionally mplayer appears to add in a wired jump at the end of the audio file... but I guess I can live with that if I have to.

So I need some way of checking if the current file is still being played.

The library doesn't appear to have a method for this.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little awkward to do this, due to the streaming nature of this implementation, and the lack of documentation.

However, this is how you do it:

```
    p = 'C:\\mymusic.mp4'
    v = VideoPlayback_MPlayer.FromPath(p)
    v.playAsync()
    while v.isPlaying:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Where you have a video player class like this:

```
class VideoPlayback_MPlayer:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def playAsync(self):
        import mplayer #pip install mplayer.py and also setup choco install mplayer myself via http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mplayer-win32/MPlayer%20and%20MEncoder/r37451%2Bg531b0a3/MPlayer-x86_64-r37451%2Bg531b0a3.7z?r=http%3A%2F%2Foss.netfarm.it%2Fmplayer%2F&ts=1442363467&use_mirror=tcpdiag
        self.isPlaying = True

        EOFDetectionArgs = "-msglevel global=6"
        self.player = mplayer.Player(args=EOFDetectionArgs.split(), stderr=None, autospawn=True)
        self.player.stdout.connect(self._EOFDetector)
        self.player.loadfile(self.path) 
        self.player.pause() # someone says online this kicks in the audio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385225/play-mp4-using-python-and-check-if-while-it-is-still-playing       

    def _EOFDetector(self, stream):
        if stream.startswith('EOF code:'):
            self.isPlaying = False

    @property
    def done(self):
        return not self.isPlaying


    def play(self):
        self.playAsync()
        while self.isPlaying:
            time.sleep(0.00001)        

    @staticmethod
    def FromPath(path):
        return VideoPlayback_MPlayer(path)
```