# how to play and take duration and stop a mp4 file in python

Tags: python, video, mp4

I have the below code to play a mp4 file. But I want to take the duration of the file and play a new video when it has stopped playing and also to to close the player. How do I do that. Tried various of things like pygame etc. But nothing is working for me

```
import os, random
import threading
import sys
playing = True
class Video(object):
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path

def play(self):
    from os import startfile
    startfile(self.path)
class Movie_MP4(Video):
    type = "MP4"

def play(folder):
        fileName = random.choice(os.listdir("E:/Shamila Stuff/campus/year 3/2nd semester/Final Project/Smart Commercial System/Smart Commercial System/commercials/"+folder));
        print(fileName);
        aaa = r"E:/Shamila Stuff/campus/year 3/2nd semester/Final Project/Smart Commercial System/Smart Commercial System/commercials/"+folder+"/"+fileName;
        movie = Video(aaa);
        movie.play()
        play('adult');
```

when I tried [Play .mp4 using python and check if/while it is still playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385225/play-mp4-using-python-and-check-if-while-it-is-still-playing) I get error `[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`